# System malfunctioning in Windows-7

Tags: windows-7

When I clicking on any folder in desktop of my laptop(Dell-Windows-7), it always points to the first folder(which is MyComputer) and opens it. Why? I scanned system fully, No virus detected. Due to any property setting changes? Please help.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a settings/registry key issue. I had similar problem.
I think you will find solutuion in [here](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/79799-35-default-action-folder-click).

Probably default action for files like .lnk have changed. 
On windows [older than Vista] you can check it by going to Tools->Folder Options->File Types tab. Scroll down and find file LNK. CLick Advanced button and review the Actions table. Compare with other PC.

The fix for Windows XP can be downloaded [here](http://www.dougknox.com/xp/fileassoc/linkfile_fix.zip). Maybe similar fix is possible for Win 7

And you can refer to [this technet topic](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/itprovistadesktopui/thread/e8631c28-4ce5-43cc-8865-b75fa2255b57) for Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably run [Malware Bytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org) or [SpyBot S&D](http://www.safer-networking.org/index2.html) to make sure there isn't anything else (malware/spyware/adware) messing with your system. A free online scan at [eSet](http://www.eset.com/us/online-scanner/) just to make sure its clean might be a good idea.

**Here is the important part;** Once you know the system is clean, open an elevated command prompt and run `SFC /SCANNOW` to run the System File Check. When it is done, reboot and see if things are back to normal.