# Browsers unable to display text

Tags: windows-7, browser

My browsers aren't able to display any text. I've tried both Chrome and IE - it seems like a system-wide issue.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOk0r.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4qxR.png]

What may the issue be?

Comment: There are a number of things this could be. More information is needed. First, what have you tried to resolve this? Did this just start? Have you tried System Restore to go back to a date before this started? Have you tried Safe Mode? Have you scanned your computer for viruses and malware? Details are important for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: It feel like some files are corrupted just dont know where to start. Its been like that for a while.  Just didnt bother to address it till now.  I've tried reinstalling the browsers, but still did not work.

Comment: Start by trying the things I suggest in [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/465313/97028) and see it helps. If you can't download the first two items, try it in reverse order. I suggest doing this in Safe Mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As predicted, turns out certain file were corrupted and affected the text encoding.

Ran this with admin privilege on dos to fix : `SFC /SCANNOW`

then reboot.  Can credit @CharlieRB for hinting me the command